# $P(A)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} I_{A}(x) f(x) dx $. Show $P(A) = 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $P(A)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  I_{A}(x)  f(x) dx  $ for a non-negative function $f$. Show that $P(A) = 0$ for $A$ being countable.

So in an intutive way this has to be true since a countable set is the union of singletons the probability of singletons is 0.

However, to bring this idea onto paper in this context seems not so easy for me. I would write $$P(A)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  I_{A}(x)  f(x) dx = \int_{A} f(x) dx = \int_{\bigcup{{a_{i}}}_{a \in A}} f(x) dx = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_{a} f(x) dx =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 0 = 0 $$

But is the step from $ \int_{\bigcup{{a_{i}}}_{a \in A}} f(x) dx = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_{a} f(x) dx $ really correct? I think I used the property that $P$ is a probability measure and then it is $\sigma$ additive but I did it more because of an intuitive feeling than because of a precise mathematical reasoning. Any help would be nice!

Comment: I think it might be easier to write that $I_A f(x) = I_{\cup a_i}f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty I_{\lbrace a_i\rbrace}f(x)$.

Comment: You are right, it is $\sigma-$additivity of the measure which enables the step.

Comment: So since it is not stated here that P is a probability measure I should write it as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} I_{\{a_i\}}f(x) dx $ and then apply the Monotone convergence theorem on it?

Comment: The point is that $dx$ (in other words Lebesgue measure) is countably additive.

Comment: Every occurrence of $I_A$ in this post should read $I_A(x)$.

Comment: @Did corrected it!